# Heroku error during deployment of mern application

Tags: heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

I just tried to deploy my first heroku application, but unfortunately I am getting an error.

The command `heroku logs --tail` throws the following error:

```
2020-02-14T16:35:34.990792+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"host=agile-wildwood-52268.herokuapp.com request_id=5edfe87f-b4c7-42ee-a856-03ab806613ec fwd="88.68.64.245" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2020-02-14T16:35:37.110579+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=agile-wildwood-52268.herokuapp.com request_id=4e0aeeee-f828-4f85-a18c-25d54bfe3221 fwd="88.68.64.245" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I don't know where this error might be caused, any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem.
I didn't have my environment variables set on the heroku dashboard.
If you get a similar problem follow those steps:

1. Go to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps
2. Click on your application
3. Go to settings and click on "reveal config vars"
4. Enter all your environment variables

Hope it helps